# How do you add dynamic html to a jQuery dialog's text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I've poured through SO looking for an answer to this (what seems to me to be a seemingly simple) question. I want to dynamically create a jquery dialog but I want to have the text/body of the dialog contain an href - that will need to be dynamically created with the dialog. Something like:

```
    var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div')); 
    var j = 1; 

    newDiv.dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:240,
    modal: true,
    text: '<a href="html://test.com">test link' + j + ' within a dialog body</a>',
    title: "MyDialog",
    buttons: {
        "Add Related": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            window.location = "addRelated.php?id="+id;                
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

The text parameter seems to only take text. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Both answers worked great. Thank you both! I don't know which one to make the primary answer so I made the more detailed one the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to create a div and appending text to it is:

```
var j = 1;
var newDiv = $('<div/>').append('<a href="html://test.com">test link' + j + ' within a dialog body</a>');
```

The jQuery UI Dialog has text property only for defining button labels (see: [option-buttons](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)).

So my snippet is:

```js
$(function () {
  var j = 1;
  var newDiv = $('<div/>').append('<a href="html://test.com">test link' + j + ' within a dialog body</a>');

  newDiv.dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:240,
    modal: true,
    title: "MyDialog",
    buttons: {
      "Add Related": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        window.location = "addRelated.php?id="+id;
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

A different way to achieve this is based on [open event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open):

```js
$(function () {
  var newDiv = $('<div/>');
  var j = 1;

  newDiv.dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:240,
    modal: true,
    title: "MyDialog",
    buttons: {
      "Add Related": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        window.location = "addRelated.php?id="+id;
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
    open: function( event, ui ) {
      $(this).append('<a href="html://test.com">test link' + j + ' within a dialog body</a>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using jQuery with jQuery.ui, you can create all your HTML in the div:

```
var newDiv = $('<div><a href="html://test.com">test link' + j + ' within a dialog body</a></div>');
newDiv.dialog(...);
```

Thus, negating the need to use the undocumented text property.